# Connecting Android application to MySQL

Tags: java, android, mysql

I have a system that is running on web and a MySQL database; these include the database connection factory to MySQL, Bean/Model, DAO and Servlets. And I am planning to create an Android application in mobile device that also needs to access the information in the MySQL. Apparently, the connection to MySQL does not work similarly with the web-based system. There are errors in the connection to MySQL in Android app. Code below

```
public Connection getConnection() {
    try {
        Context initContext = new InitialContext();
        Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
        DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup(getDatasource());
        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
        return conn;
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DBConnectionFactoryImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DBConnectionFactoryImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

How can I exactly connect my mobile application with my existing MySQL database?

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853367/jdbc-vs-web-service-for-android

Comment: Keep in mind that it is insecure to use a direct MySQL connection in a public app. As long this is something internal or a diagnostic tool, you don't need to care about it.